# Error when trying to run bokeh-server

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, bokeh

I have recently installed the latest version of bokeh and am trying to run a server from the terminal in Ubuntu 14.04. I am getting the following error:

```
user@host:~$ bokeh-server
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/bokeh-server", line 3, in <module>
 import bokeh.server
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/server/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
 from bokeh.server.utils.reload import robust_reloader
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/server/utils/reload.py", line 8, in <module>
 from werkzeug.serving import _iter_module_files
 ImportError: cannot import name _iter_module_files
```

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems bokeh server is not compatible with the new version of "werkzeug".

To fix this replace the line

```
from werkzeug.serving import _iter_module_files
```

by

```
from werkzeug._reloader import _iter_module_files
```

in your "reload.py" (in your case located in "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/server/utils/").

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed one master, see: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/1840

Thanks!!